# Access or Display comments left by users abt the application

Tags: android, comments

i am new to android domain . Can u please let me know . is it possible to access or display comments left by users about the application using the api given in the sdk if 'yes' please fwd link where i can study further.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the Android Market and comments users leave on there, I believe the only way to view comments is to use one of the third party Market access sites like http://www.androlib.com/.

There's certainly nothing in the SDK that would let you access this information; it's only used for application development.

Comment: thanks for the response ,
 i know that we can see the comments in androlib and third party sites . but my query was how to access them(comments) i.e. how these sites access appplication details such as Comments left by the user .. ?

Comment: These individual sites are able to scrape comments and other information from the Android Market because the people running them have spent the time to figure out the proprietary protocols behind the Android Market.  There is no public API access to this information.

Comment: thanks . i was planning for an application that would display comments and much more . But if given info is true , i may not be able to proceed .. 

thank u again for response .it was helpful